# Rails - error in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

Rails 3.2.3

In production mode I have an error and it displays standard "we're sorry" page. In development mode there is no error.

I need to get more information about the error so I want to turn off  "we're sorry" page and see the error. I know it has to be lauched as "rails s -e production" and I do it at my local computer.  But how can turn off "we're sorry" page?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In config/environments/production.rb

temporally change

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```

to

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at the logs in `log/production.log`. Usually this has to do with assets, maybe you need to put `gem 'therubyracer'` into the Gemfile.

The error page is displayed by some entries in the rack middleware (i believe `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions` and `ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions`). You could always add them to your application, but probably it's easier to check the logs. "Turning off" the page actually means adding stuff to display the exception page.

Comment: The question is "How can turn off "we're sorry" page?"

Comment: I've added some information about that, but in the end I think you should check the logs and not spend time configuring your production to match your environment.

Comment: You cannot turn it off, you can change the error page on your public folder.

Comment: @ucas clemente, Yes, it also would be helpful. How do I add stuff to the exception page?

Comment: For Future reference it would make more sense for anyone check logs as per this answer. i assumed with my answer to the above there was a very good reason to not.

Comment: I am working on a fresh, new app. There's 0 traffic. I am running into a most elusive bug that I would like to debug with web_console gem. But, I can't do that until I can show the actual error on the page - which is the only scene where I see the error message. I do not see it even when I simulate a headless request in the production console in shell. So, I think op's request is understandable

Answer (score 1):

I always forget setting the environment variable for the `SECRET_KEY_BASE`. Look at `config/secrets.yml`.