# Heroku rails 4 devise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I have a rails app that I am developing on heroku. My app works completely on my local machine, however on the heroku domain (myapp.herokuapp.com...) once I hit submit on my devise powered signup page I get redirected to a page "/users" (that doesn't even exist) and I get this error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

Of course the logs shows absolutely NOTHING beyond normal and is completely worthless.

I *should* be redirected to my index page with an notice for the new user to check their email for a confirmation link. The email is not sent nor am I redirected to the index page on heroku. However when I try this samething locally I get a confermation link and I am redirected like I am supposed to be.

There is no difference between the two (heroku and my localhost) code wise besides my database.yml, and gem file (switching between sqlite3 and not.)

Before setting up confirmable with devise, on my localhost I was able to go to the login page and login with my newly created password/username. However on heroku (before setting up confirmable with devise) I was STILL redirected to the /users page but this time I was able to manually type in the index login page URL and login with my password/user name that I just created.

Why is devise (or whatever) redirecting me to /users? I have been stuck on this issus for two weeks, please help. Or at least point me to the right direction on where I can get hits on what is causing this issue. Thank you in advance!

UPDATE

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Works as it should. But I am still having the error. So the rake did nothing.

Comment: Have you run your migrations on heroku? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Yes, the rake seems to be working, but I am still getting the same errors.  So the db:migrate didn't fix anything

Comment: This answer helped me figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601484/rails-error-in-production-mode

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up email sending in Heroku? For example a Sendgrid addons.

And for the redirecting: [How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign_in, sign_out, and or sign_up in Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-or-sign_up)

Comment: Yes I did, I am using mailtrap. Thanks for the other link. However I have tried after_inactive_sign_up_path_for in the past and I still am getting the same error. Thanks