# Rails: hide errors errors in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I run my rails application (Rails 4.2.x) with the passenger module for Apache.

Is there a way to not show error messages:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: production env is not configured to show stack traces. But even if you want you can configure that. Already i can such a question posted. Check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601484/rails-error-in-production-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the following setting is set to false in your `config/environment/production.rb` file:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't run your production mode like this, you may hack it that it would show errors like that. But you got all your errors in your logs.

check log/production.log for your errors.

Comment: Problem is that it shows the errors now. But I don't want it. How can I turn this off for production?

Comment: I am sorry..
`config.consider_all_requests_local = false` would be the solution in your config/environments/production.rb

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the following setting in your `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```